# refresh counting value in javascript in jquery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have ajax like this

```
function InitiateBrandBudgetTreeView() {
    $.post(root + "PF/GetBrandData", null, function (data) {
        try {
            brandData = data;
            var rootNodeBrand = GenerateBrandObject(brandData);
            tvHtmlBrand = "";
            GenerateBrandTreeView(rootNodeBrand);
            var treeviewBrand = "<ul>" + tvHtmlBrand + "</ul>";
            //draw tree
            if (brandDynatree !== null)
                $("#cpTreeArea").dynatree("destroy");
            $("#cpTreeArea").html(treeviewBrand);
            brandDynatree = $("#cpTreeArea").dynatree({
                checkbox: false,
                selectMode: 3,
                minExpandLevel: 4,
                onDblClick: function (node, event) {
                    // Check jika sudah exists
                    if (IsBrandAlreadyExists(node.data.key, "M")) { // check di multiple select
                        MsgBox(node.data.title + " already exists !");
                        MsgBox("Either " + node.data.title + " or it's parent or it's child already exists !");
                        return false;
                    } else if (IsBrandAlreadyExists(node.data.key, "S")) { //check di selected table
                        MsgBox(node.data.title + " already exists on selected list !");
                        MsgBox("Either " + node.data.title + " or it's parent or it's child already exists on selected list !");
                        return false;
                    }
                    // Append brand to selected table
                    var regex = new RegExp(/\./g);
                    var level = node.data.key == '0' ? 0 : node.data.key.split('.').length;
                    var brandObj = { Code: node.data.key, Name: node.data.title, Level: level };
                    var cnt = $("#selGridBrandSelectedBody tr").length;

                    var selectTmpl =
                                '<tr><td>${Name}</td>' +
                                '<td><input type="text" maxlength="6" style="width:50px;text-align:center" value=' + RefreshRowValue(cnt) + '></td>' +
                                '<td><span class="item-remove">remove</span></td></tr>';
                    $.tmpl(selectTmpl, brandObj).appendTo("#selGridBrandSelectedBody");

                    $(".selGridBrandSelectedEmptyRow").remove();
                    RefreshGridSelectedBrand();
                },
                onRender: function (node, nodeSpan) {
                    $.each($("#cpTreeArea").find("a.dynatree-title"), function (i, node) {
                        $(this).attr("title", $(this).html());
                    });
                }
            });
            HideLoading();
            $("#selGridBrandBodyMultiple").empty();
            winAddBrand.show();
        } catch (ex) {
            //MsgErr("Error while generate brand");
        }
    })
}

function RefreshRowValue(cnt) {
    var result;
    result += cnt;
    return result
}

function RefreshGridSelectedBrand() {
    $("#selGridBrandSelectedBody .item-remove").click(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        if ($("#selGridBrandSelectedBody tr").length == 0)
            $("#selGridBrandSelectedTmplEmpty").tmpl().appendTo("#selGridBrandSelectedBody");
    });
}
```

I want the value of RefreshRowValue is refresh every I select or remove the selected value by using this formula. But I don't know how to loop and refresh on that code section.

> (100/sum of the selected value)

If I select 
**3 values**, so the cntResult will be

```
50
25
25
```

**2 value**

```
50
50
```

**1 value**

```
100
```

**4 values**

```
25
25
25
25
```

each rows of value if we calculated must be 100%. I'm stuck on this. My value that I made is not refresh. Any help will be very welcome

Comment: i dont understand clearly what you mean with "if the selected value more than 1" you mean is possible to select the same value more than 1 time, could you add others examples?

Comment: it is possible to select more than 1 value. I just want the selected value that I choose the percentage in my cntResult is refresh by using formula (100/count(s) of the selected value).

Comment: your question is not clear, plz show us the full version of your codes, $.tmpl looks like a custom jquery plugin ,what is the code of it?

Comment: yes it's jquery plugin. I have update my code